# How to stop a database result from re-appearing once value is taken

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a car rental project, when renting an available car from database table CAR with `car ID` as primary key, I insert data into table `RESERVATION` with `reservation ID` as primary key and `car ID` as foreign key from `car` table.

However, I don't want the car I just rented out to appear as an "available car" to rent. What query should I write in order to hide it?

```
Select cars.* 
from cars, reservation 
where ?
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not need to update any tables to hide the car.

When selecting the list of available cars for display, use this SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM Car WHERE CarID NOT IN (SELECT CarID FROM Reservation)
```

This will exclude any cars that have already been reserved. That's the basic idea, anyway.

It's likely that reservations are only good for a certain period, and the user may be attempting to reserve a different period, so you might need something more complicated, like:

```
SELECT * FROM Car WHERE CarID NOT IN
(
    SELECT CarID
    FROM   Reservation
    WHERE  StartDate < @DesiredEndDate
    AND    EndDate   > @DesiredStartDate
)
```

This will provide a list of cars that do not appear in a reservation that overlaps the user's desired reservation time.

Comment: worked perfectly man, thank you so much.
One more think if you can help me more, how to prevent a customer from renting a second car when he already has a car rent?
customerID is in table reservation too.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a join query as:

```
Select C.carID
from @Car C
Left join @Reservation R on C.carID = R.carID
where R.reservationID is null
```